# how to make a loop function with "adonis"?

Tags: r, vegan

```
 data(dune)
 data(dune.env)

 results<-list()
 for (i in colnames(dune.env)){
         results[[i]]<- adonis(dune ~ i, data=dune.env, permutations=99)
  }
```

When I test each name in `colnames(dune.env)`, it can work. 
But it can not work in the loop function above. I think it is due to the `i` in the loop fuction has `" "`. How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know nothing about adonis, but I do know that formulas are `language` objects which do not take nicely to being treated as though they were ordinary `character` objects.

```
for (i in colnames(dune.env)){ 
           form <- as.formula(paste("dune", i, sep="~"))
           results[[i]]<- adonis(form, data=dune.env, permutations=99)
           }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's really what I want. Merry Chirstamas!