# Extract R2 values from multiple adonis results

Tags: r, vegan, multivariate-testing

I am wondering if there is some way how to extract results from `adonis` function in `vegan` package and possibly save it by `write.table`?

I mean other way than `print` results to console and copy-past R2 value to Excel.

This can be especially useful when running `adonis` iteratively for multiple combinations and saving objects with results into one `list` as suggested [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34445352/7886302).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can extract the needed parameters from the model. I will use the linked example:

```
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
```

lapply is used here instead of a loop:

```
results <- lapply(colnames(dune.env), function(x){
  form <- as.formula(paste("dune", x, sep="~")) 
  z <- adonis(form, data = dune.env, permutations=99)
  return(as.data.frame(z$aov.tab)) #convert anova table to a data frame
}
)
```

this will produce a list of data frames each having the form

```
> results[[1]]
#output
          Df SumsOfSqs   MeanSqs  F.Model        R2 Pr(>F)
A1         1 0.7229518 0.7229518 3.638948 0.1681666   0.01
Residuals 18 3.5760701 0.1986706       NA 0.8318334     NA
Total     19 4.2990219        NA       NA 1.0000000     NA
```

now you can name the list elements with the appropriate variable:

```
names(results) <- colnames(dune.env)
```

convert to a data frame:

```
results <- do.call(rbind, results)
#output
                      Df SumsOfSqs   MeanSqs  F.Model        R2 Pr(>F)
A1.A1                  1 0.7229518 0.7229518 3.638948 0.1681666   0.01
A1.Residuals          18 3.5760701 0.1986706       NA 0.8318334     NA
A1.Total              19 4.2990219        NA       NA 1.0000000     NA
Moisture.Moisture      3 1.7281651 0.5760550 3.585140 0.4019903   0.01
Moisture.Residuals    16 2.5708567 0.1606785       NA 0.5980097     NA
Moisture.Total        19 4.2990219        NA       NA 1.0000000     NA
Management.Management  3 1.4685918 0.4895306 2.767243 0.3416107   0.01
Management.Residuals  16 2.8304301 0.1769019       NA 0.6583893     NA
Management.Total      19 4.2990219        NA       NA 1.0000000     NA
Use.Use                2 0.5531507 0.2765754 1.255190 0.1286690   0.30
Use.Residuals         17 3.7458712 0.2203454       NA 0.8713310     NA
Use.Total             19 4.2990219        NA       NA 1.0000000     NA
Manure.Manure          4 1.5238805 0.3809701 2.059193 0.3544714   0.03
Manure.Residuals      15 2.7751414 0.1850094       NA 0.6455286     NA
Manure.Total          19 4.2990219        NA       NA 1.0000000     NA
```

and now you can save it to a csv or any other format you like:

```
write.csv(results, "res.csv")
```

If only R squared is needed change the lapply call to:

```
results <- lapply(colnames(dune.env), function(x){
  form <- as.formula(paste("dune", x, sep="~"))
  z <- adonis(form, data = dune.env, permutations=99)
  return(data.frame(name = rownames(z$aov.tab), R2 = z$aov.tab$R2))
}
)
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Playing with number of columns in final table is possible as well. `return(data.frame(name = rownames(z$aov.tab), R2 = z$aov.tab$R2, P = z$aov.tab$P, Df = z$aov.tab$Df))`